# jQuery mouseenter, mouseleave unexpected behavior in FF

Tags: jquery

What I’m trying to do is to append a div on `mouseenter` event and set the `top` property of that new div to the event’s mouse position. The problem I’m getting is that when I enter the mouse closer to the event element’s edge (for example a quarter of the element’s width and the element is 60px wide) the event fires alternately with the `mouseleave` event resulting with blinking effect. The problem I have noticed only in FF. Also the problem won’t occur if I set static `top` property (for example height of the event’s element). I’ve already tried to solve this problem using timeout. I’m not to sure if I’m doing something wrong here or the problem is with FF.

Any ideas on how I could prevent that behavior? Please be easy as it is my first post here :)

Example:

HTML

```
<div class="columnWrap">
  <div class="colDesc"></div>
  <div class="column col_hover col_gradient"></div>
  <div class="colVal"></div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="chart1_colPopup colPopup"></div>
</div>
```

That how I have bound my events

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var colHoverTimer;
var popupOpen = false;

$('.column.col_hover').mouseenter(function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (popupOpen === false){
        popupOpen = true;
        var trigger = $(e.target).closest('.col_hover');
        colHoverTimer= setTimeout(function(){columnHover(e, trigger)}, 500);
    }
});

$('.column.col_hover').mouseleave(function(e){
        console.log('mouseout');
        clearTimeout(colHoverTimer);
        $('body > .colPopup').remove();
        popupOpen = false;
});
});
```

Function appending the discussed element to the DOM:

```
function columnHover(event, trigger){   
  var targetPopup = trigger.siblings('.colPopup');
  targetPopup = targetPopup.clone().appendTo('Body').css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'display' : ''});

  var colOffset = trigger.offset();
  var popupWidth = targetPopup.width();
  var popupHeight = targetPopup.height();
  var colWrapPos = trigger.closest('.columnWrap').position();
  var containerWidth = trigger.closest('div#chartWrapper').width();

  var posX = (colWrapPos.left > (containerWidth / 2)) ? colOffset.left - popupWidth : colOffset.left + (trigger.width() / 2);
  var posY = event.pageY - popupHeight;
  //var posY = colOffset.top;

  targetPopup.css({'left' : posX, 'top' : posY});
  targetPopup.css('visibility', '');        
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make a jsfiddle.net to illustrate your issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `var posY = event.pageY - popupHeight - 1;` to ensure the popup is created a bit off from the cursor position.

The problem I believe is that Firefox allows decimal values even for pixel positions. This means the popup is  created right below the cursor, which of course means you have left `.col_hover` and mouseout fires, which means your back in. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Solved! Thank you for the quick replay. As you said, the problem was indeed that the new div was appending right below the mouse cursor. However it was difficult to realize because in other browsers the mouseout event wasn’t firing on the appended div until the mouse cursor has been moved out.